# Infinity Scroll Android and Laravel 5.2

Tags: android, listview, laravel-5

I am trying to implement Laravel pagination for the first time and I am lost at what to do.

I use the following to pull the data from the database

```
$data = DB::table('news')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(15);
    return $data;
```

and I got the following

```
{"total":3,"per_page":15,"current_page":1,"last_page":1,"next_page_url":null,"prev_page_url":null,"from":1,"to":3,"data":[{"id":1,"news_id":"3869577","news_title":"First Title","news_content":"First", "created_at":"2016-06-06 09:20:33","updated_at":"2016-06-06 09:20:33"},{"id":2,"news_id":"11081411","news_title":"Second Title","news_content":"Second.","created_at":"2016-06-07 07:20:33","updated_at":"2016-06-07 07:20:33"},{"id":3,"news_id":"14646385","news_title":"Third Title","news_content":"Third","created_at":"2016-06-07 14:58:33","updated_at":"2016-06-07 14:58:33"}]}
```

I then created `EndlessScrollListener` that implements `AbsListView.OnScrollListener`

On my fragment, I then have:

```
 listview.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
            // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
            customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
            // or customLoadMoreDataFromApi(totalItemsCount);
            return true; // ONLY if more data is actually being loaded; false otherwise.
        }
    });
```

Then

```
// Append more data into the adapter
public void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int offset) {
  // This method probably sends out a network request and appends new data items to your adapter. 
  // Use the offset value and add it as a parameter to your API request to retrieve paginated data.
  // Deserialize API response and then construct new objects to append to the adapter
}
```

**Questions**

1. How do I contruct the next url to fetch more data?
2. Do I have to capture the new url on my route in Laravel?

Thanks for the help

Comment: call your data fetching task inside customLoadMoreDataFromApi()

Comment: That I already know, there two questions I asked above 1 and 2.

Comment: You do not need to construct the url - laravle does this for you - it's the next page url property which is null if there is no next page since you have total of 3 elements with 15 per page. 2. Just call this url, laravel already fetches it correctly.

Comment: @FrankProvost You are saying that if my initial url was `http://myapp.com/news`, then to fetch page 2 of data, the url should still be `http://myapp.com/news`? It returned 3, it was just a test run

Comment: it will actually be http://myapp.com/news?page=3 for your 30-45 element that's why you do not need a new route. Just add more entries to your database or adjust your query to return more - then you will see it in the next_page_url response

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically just going to directly answer your two questions

1. Laravel will give you the URL if you have more than 15 elements. You can then extract the url from the next_page_url param you just showed in your snippet. It is null because you have < 15 Elements and you set Pagination for 15 Elements.
2. You do not need to create a new route for this. The url will call your route where you setup pagination. The pagination function will listen for the given parameters (...?page=2) and will give you the matching elements.

Comment: Thanks, let me test and see.